# Need a Javascript library that supports loading animation scripts

Tags: javascript, animation

Looking for a Javascript library that supports loading of a basic an animation file/script(could be in a XML format), so animation scripts can be downloaded on the fly and played to the user.

The application I'm building allows users to download an animation file from the web and allows the user to play this animation file.

I'm sure there are plenty around but can't seem to locate any.

Comment: Do you need a library just for this purpose? 

If the scripts are self contained (i.e. they load whatever elements they need into the DOM and required libraries), all you need to do is add a script element with a *scr* attribute referencing the script.

Or is that the functionality you are looking for? Something that packages the animation into a single script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to make my own animation format in the end.
The $fx() library (http://fx.inetcat.com/) is what animation library I'm using since its very simple. Then basically made a turned it into a XML format and parsed it with jQuery and turn them into $fx() objects.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of great animation libraries like [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) or [YUI Animation](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/animation/) that has been used to build impressive stuff like [Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/).  What do you mean exactly by:

> downloaded on the fly and shown to the user

Comment: Yeah I know many animation libraries just like you suggested. But just like those none can load an animation file/script(could be say in a XML format) and run them.

Comment: The closest thing possible would be to use a utility like [YUI Get](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/get/) that is used to dynamically load  javascript/css.  In your case, the JavaScript that would be dynamically loaded would have to be written in animation library of your choice.  But your right though, none of those can load an animation file in XML or anything other than the library that would execute it.